# How to manually set magnitude of shock for IRF in vars package

Tags: r, variables

I'm using the following code to run a Structural VAR and plot IRFs using the `vars` package. In the `irf` command, the default magnitude of the shock is +1 Standard Deviation. Is there a way that I can set this to something else (let's say a positive 1% impulse instead of 1 standard deviation)?

```
data <- structure(c(1.54054238132604, 5.22775636647117, 1.75154671443607, 
-4.00396437623925, -4.99849595390862, -3.58991362838901, -2.08646214793927, 
4.38408682550573, -1.32609419137286, -10.0477865139619, -10.5789067079456, 
3.53586648125426, 3.80285045230506, 4.54214390385599, 5.25998848716807, 
4.53265591355598, 4.18968593558051, 3.53167443997122, 2.68286514861102, 
2.28625948262682, 1.9539414753903, 2.30401026783675), .Dim = c(11L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("GDP", "CPI")), index = structure(c(1514764800, 
1522540800, 1530403200, 1538352000, 1546300800, 1554076800, 1561939200, 
1569888000, 1577836800, 1585699200, 1593561600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"))

library(vars)

var.model <- vars::VAR(data, p=1, type = 'cons')
svar.model <- vars::BQ(var.model)

plot(irf(svar.namibia, impulse = "CPI", response = "GDP", n.ahead = 20, runs = 1000))
```